# Java unable to load class for JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a program in intelJ that connects to a SQL database, but I receive this error when it tries to find the drivers.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I've checked that the directory I use is correct when using Class.forname

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

and it points to the correct location within the Jar file for the driver. I'd assume that that java is unable to find the class for whatever reason, as I've done the exact same thing with a second project which works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the driver JAR to the classpath of the project.

If you're using a simple Java project: right click on the project in IntelliJ IDEA > Open Module Settings. Then, Project Settings > Libraries. Click on +. Select Java. Browse to the driver JAR. Click OK and it should work.

Comment: I've added the .jar to the libraries, but the same error still occurs.

Comment: You need to add it to the [**module's dependencies**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html). The Libraries section just lists the libraries of this project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the [**module's dependencies**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html). The Libraries section just lists the libraries of this project.

Comment: Should i import mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11 as a JAR or as a library? I've tried both but neither of them worked, is there anything else I need to add. I also get a message on my project structure menu saying that gradle may change the module's configuration after reimporting. Could that have anything to do with this?

Comment: If you are using Gradle - you must manage all dependencies via the build.gradle file. So you should add it in your Gradle configuration, then IDE will automatically include it into project classpath when you build and run.

Comment: Thanks, what should I add to my gradle dependencies?